# how to create an animation fade in UIImageView from left to right (alpha gradient)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

how to create an animation fade in UIImageView from left to right.

from left to right i mean alpha gradient , not move from left to right.

thanks for any help

like this
[image]

Comment: Post some image what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest to what you want:

[How to apply partial fade in-out in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346837/how-to-apply-partial-fade-in-out-in-ios)

The awesome dude post a working code even.