# UIView Fade Animation Left-to-Right

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Currently I'm able to make a view fade out all at once, but I'm wondering if there's a simple way to make a view fade from left to right?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        _view.alpha = 1;
    } completion: ^(BOOL finished) { 
        _view.hidde = YES;
    }];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561696/how-to-create-an-animation-fade-in-uiimageview-from-left-to-right-alpha-gradien

Comment: Try animating the view's frame (or constraint if you're using auto layout)?