# SKSpriteNode animating gradient

Tags: ios, gradient, sprite-kit, cagradientlayer

I have a SKSpriteNode that starts out transparent, and I want to make it fully visible starting at one side and moving to the other, ending with the whole sprite visible.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346837/how-to-apply-partial-fade-in-out-in-ios) addressed the issue with CALayers on UIViews, but it doesn't seem as though we can access the CALayers of an SKSpriteNode.

Is there a way to apply animating gradients to SKSpriteNodes?

Comment: you looked at SKEffectNode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it using crop nodes. You can run it by creating a new "SpriteKit Game" project in Xcode and replacing `touchesBegan` in MyScene.m:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

        SKCropNode *cropNode = [SKCropNode node];

        // maskNode is twice as big as the sprite:
        // fully masked on the left, fully visible on the right
        SKNode *masked = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] size:sprite.frame.size];
        SKNode *shown  = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] size:sprite.frame.size];
        shown.position = CGPointMake(sprite.frame.size.width, 0);

        SKNode *maskNode = [SKNode node];
        [maskNode addChild:masked];
        [maskNode addChild:shown];

        cropNode.maskNode = maskNode;
        cropNode.position = location;

        [self addChild:cropNode];
        [cropNode addChild:sprite];

        SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(-sprite.frame.size.width, 0) duration:5];
        [maskNode runAction:fadeIn];
    }
}
```