# Fade UIImageView gradually

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I want my UIImaveView to fade out gradually from the middle all the way to the left until it disappears, I don't want to add a gradient layer above it since its doesn't make it disappear, so technically the left side of the UIImageView should not be visible,

Thank you in advance,

Comment: If you dont want to apply gradient to the UIImageview then add the UIView above the UIImageview, try some fade out on the UIView...

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346837/how-to-apply-partial-fade-in-out-in-ios

Comment: Are you talking about something like animateWithDuration?

Comment: changing the alpha value of the uiimageview with animation??